# run php artisan websockets:serve automatically without supervisor

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, pusher, laravel-websockets

i have a laravel project with [beyondcode/laravel-websockets](https://docs.beyondco.de/laravel-websockets/) package.

Everytime i want to run the websockets, i need to run:

```
php artisan websockets:serve
```

I can't do this for producction.

I don't have access to the apache production server, so i can't install the [supervisor](https://docs.beyondco.de/laravel-websockets/1.0/basic-usage/starting.html#keeping-the-socket-server-running-with-supervisord) package, all i can modify about the apache is my .htaccess file.

**How can i run this command or something for start my websocket app automatically?**

Comment: Have you tried call Artisan command from your php file? `Artisan::call('websockets:serve');`

Comment: Please move the answer from your question text to a separate answer text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just made a route like this one for run the command

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'internal', 'middleware' => ['jwt.verify','admin']], function(){
    Route::get('sockets/serve', function(){
        \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::call('websockets:serve');
    });
});
```

I don't know if its the best option but its working 100% fine, so I am satisfied.
When the route is called, it keeps in an infinite time lapse, that's because the command is a listener and never returns a response, so the route will never return a response, just close the window or something else.

Thanks again to [Huy Trịnh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2373106/huy-tr%E1%BB%8Bnh)

Comment: Not working for me. Stack at loading. Nothing shows.